# How to create a strike through in an equation in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm not sure how to create a strike through in the Microsoft equation editor.

### Example 1

[image]

### Example 2

[image]

In LaTeX one is able to use the `cancel` command for this, but I'm failing to find an approach to this in Word.

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to use a strike-through on the number you're wanting to cross out. It's definitely not as nice looking, and probably quite annoying to do so one by one.

Comment: @DrZoo thanks, that's not suitable though as it wouldn't cross through a word

Comment: What do you mean by cross through? It would not "cross through" as in cross through diagonally like you've drawn? Although the answer below achieves the overall goal, I think the horizontal strike-through would be more consistent looking.

Comment: Yes I mean it wouldn't be as I have drawn it

Answer (score 19):

My workaround (not quite sure what the names of the menus are in the English version):
1. Open a math zone
2. Open *Accent* menu and select *Boxed formulas* (or type **\rect**)
3. Right-click on the placeholder, select *Border property*, and remove one by one each side of the border; finally insert the desired strike through, from the same menu 
4. Select the template you have built and save it as a new equation.

Now you have a new template you can use with any expression. 
[image]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots too? Does it strikethrough the whole equation, or can you select only parts of it too?

Comment: kindly show an example

Comment: Ok, I've just edited my post with a screenshot of the output. You can place your new equation/template in any part of the equation. It fits to the dimensions of the content. You've got to place the template before typing your expression.

Comment: Works nice. But note that you (or at least I) had to change the object to "Professional", whatever that is. Then I could adjust the borders. Also, it's a bit tedious (aka, a workaround).

Answer (score 6):

The LaTeX `cancel` command is not supported in Word's equation editor. I've struggled with this before and the solution below is the closest I got.

Let's take 3/7 as an example and cancel the 3:

1. Insert a new equation object and add a fraction object, type `7` as the denominator.

   [image]
2. Select the numerator, then on the `Insert` tab click `Quick Parts` and choose `Field...`.
3. On the field name list choose `Eq` and click the `Field Codes` button.
4. In the `Field codes` textbox type `EQ \O(3,/)`. The `\O` flag stands for "Overstrike", and it superimposes its parameters on top of each other. In this example it will produce `3` with a slash.

   [image]
5. Click `OK` and you'll get this result:

   [image]

There are a few limitations to this approach. It's hard to insert and impossible to edit properly. It also doesn't scale to larger (wider) objects since you're just getting a slash character on top, not a real diagonal line from the top right corner to the bottom left.

I'd be happy to find a better solution, other than placing a line drawing object over the relevant area of the equation.

*Note: screenshots taken using Word 2010*

Comment: Thanks for your response! let's hope someone has a secret solution. What an awful experience using word has been for me, the tables, the equations, the images  of course inexperience never helps I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

For single characters there is another neat workaround using `\hsmash` which gives an object zero width.

Open a formula field. Then, for one struck through character type the following sequence (space does matter!). Make sure you use the "professional" setting for entering formulas.

1. `\hsmash`
2. [space]
3. [character of choice]
4. [space]
5. `"/"` (this prints / rather than creating a fraction)
6. [space]

[image: struck through "a" example]

This should be quite robust, but you need to follow the exact sequence, otherwise it won't place the characters in the right spot.

Comment: screenshot inline rather than link would be helpful

Comment: well I totally would have liked to do that l but it won't let me since I don't have any reputation

Answer (score 3):

I found GAM's answer to work well, but on MacOS the Border Properties right-click menu does not open. A workaround is to enter the equation in Powerpoint, where the right-click menu is called Math Options. I added the strikethrough there, then was able to copy and paste the equation into Word. The bug and workaround are discussed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2016-equations-boxed-equation-options/a4e5fa3b-19c3-4165-8796-af9469c3c103).

Answer (score 2):

Old post I know, and maybe things have changed. With Word 2016 (iMac version)... simply typing the strike through variable as text (ie, select it and tap the strike through font option), then coping and pasting that into my equation worked. You had to watch those irritating auto “smart selection” options etc, or it would try and paste in paragraph marks too.
See example screenshot.
[image: Microsoft Equation Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

GAM's boxed-equation method works well.  Once you have created the first "canceled" term, simply copy it to each additional location and overtype the text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS users border options are not available in Word Equation Editor so:

1. Go into Excel or Powerpoint > Insert > Equation>  type `\rect()` to get a boxed equation.
2. Right click > math options > add diagonal
3. Right click > math options > remove [top, bottom, left, right] borders
4. Copy and paste into Word
5. Right click > save equation (for use in equation drop down menu at upper right

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Here's what it looks like]

Answer (score -1):

The workaround from Atzmon is actually excellent. The strike through option is ok but does not look like a standard way of doing simplifications in Math.

The only difference with the new version of Word is that after clicking on the insert tab you need to click on the Text option in order to see Quickparts in the menu. Everything else is as Atzmon explained and described. The font will look slightly bigger than usual in the equation, but it is not very noticeable.

The box with no borders method works as well, but it is a bit more time consuming,

MS Word version 1907